# Replace missing data in SAS with prediction: Regression Imputation

Tags: sas

I have a SAS data set with missing data in multiple columns. I would like replace the missing data with a prediction based on the other data in the data set. [Here](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/sas/seminars/missing_data/Missing%20Data%20Techniques_UCLA.pdf) a link that describes the method but doesn't show me how to do it. How do I replace the missing values with a prediction?

EDIT:
The method I had in mind was just using Proc Reg then apply the coefficents to the missing data to generate the estimate. Does this answer your question?

Comment: Right now this is too broad - as that paper among others explains, there are _lots_ of ways to do this.  What's your method of predicting?

Answer (score 2):

`PROC STDIZE`, `PROC EXPAND`, and `PROC MI` are all capable of performing different kinds of imputations on your data depending on exactly how you want do determine the 'prediction'.

For simple things like replacing with the mean, `PROC STDIZE` is the way to go.  `PROC MI` is the most advanced - it performs multiple imputation.  `PROC EXPAND` is appropriate if you have time-series data, as it will try to work out what the correct value is for that point in the time series.

Answer (score 2):

If you have missing data in multiple columns you'll require multiple regressions. This probably isn't a good way to do this, but to answer the question - what you're requesting is called scoring a dataset and you can use `PROC SCORE`.

An alternative method is in your regression procedure request an `OUTPUT` data set that contains the predicted values for that regression.

```
output out=predicted1 p=pred_var_missing;
```

As a matter of methodology, I recommend @Joe's method instead.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to @Joe 's answer, if you tell us why you want to do this imputation, we can provide better advice. I wrote a blog post called [How to Ask a Statistics Question](http://www.statisticalanalysisconsulting.com/how-to-ask-a-statistics-question/)  that may help.

However, often, single imputation is a bad method. More particularly, if you are going to do further analysis on this data (with the imputed values) then single imputation will underestimate the variability of the data and give wrong results.

PROC MI is usually a better approach.